# Вопрос по select - option и выводу POST запроса

Tags: php, sql

Есть select, который подтягивает данные ФИО с базы.
При заполнении формы выбирается ФИО.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При передаче POST из формы передается ФИО, я хочу передавать ID, тк в базе поля "название группы" и "id преподавателя". Подскажите, как это можно реализовать?

код селектора:

```
                
                <form action="" method="post">
                <select name="Tid">
                <?php
                while ($option=$selteach->fetch_object()){?>
                <option><?php echo $option->FIO;?></option>
                <?php } ?>
               </select>
```

запросы к базе:

```
$selteach = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT `TNumb` AS 'Tid', CONCAT_WS(' ', Surname, Name, MidName) AS 'FIO' FROM `Teachers`");
$sql = "INSERT INTO `Groups` (`GroupName`, `TNumb`) values ('$GroupName', '$Tid')";
```

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно тегу `option` добавить атрибут `value` в котором указывать ID который и будет передавать на сервер. Т.к. `value` - значение пункта списка, которое будет отправлено на сервер или прочитано с помощью скриптов.

То есть ваш код для списка должен принять такой вид:

```
<form action="" method="post">
<select name="Tid">
<?php
while ($option=$selteach->fetch_object()){?>
    <option value="<?= $option->ID ?>"><?php echo $option->FIO;?></option>
<?php } ?>
</select>
```